# IIS : The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion. (2147943453, 8007041d)

Tags: iis-6

Can someone suggest a way out of this issue please?
Can't start IIS either through command prompt or through iis itself.

IISRESET in command prompt throws the below error:-
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion. (2147943453, 8007041d)
I have IIS 6.2(Build 9200) and OS is Win 8.1 Enterprise

Comment: Ok, I managed to fix it by running the below command from command prompt-->sfc /scannow

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this problem before for IIS6,7 and IIS10. I tried for a very long time but it was not solved by any method.

The definitive and permanent solution is IIS uninstall and reinstall. When IIS is removed, you also need to delete it in `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv` folder.